# xamarin app on real ios device from windows without connecting device to mac - not correctly starting

Tags: ios, xamarin, hot-reload

I just use the autogenerated example xamarin Application in VisualStudio 2022 (V17.3.7).
I can compile and download the App to the iPhone. The application allows to start, but immediatelly after I get the exception 'No class inheriting from a valid Application Delegate found in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDEADCEA-707F-4FEF-AE7E-B29A25BE7348/Documents/xamarin.iOS.content/xamarin.iOS.exe'

Here the full log output:

```
2022-10-25 11:11:38.673 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3726:230509] Xamarin.iOS: Processing: 'start profiler: no'

2022-10-25 11:11:38.673 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3726:230482] Xamarin.iOS: Profiler not loaded (disabled)

Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.exe [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/netstandard.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Xml.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Numerics.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Data.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Transactions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Drawing.Common.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Net.Http.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Web.Services.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [External]
Thread started:  #2
Thread started:  #3
2022-10-25 11:11:39.357 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3726:230482] Content folder: /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDEADCEA-707F-4FEF-AE7E-B29A25BE7348/Documents/xamarin.iOS.content

2022-10-25 11:11:39.357 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3726:230482] App path /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDEADCEA-707F-4FEF-AE7E-B29A25BE7348/Documents/xamarin.iOS.content/xamarin.iOS.exe

**System.Exception:** 'No class inheriting from a valid Application Delegate found in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDEADCEA-707F-4FEF-AE7E-B29A25BE7348/Documents/xamarin.iOS.content/xamarin.iOS.exe'

Thread started: <Thread Pool> #4
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #5
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #7
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #8
2022-10-25 11:11:52.344 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3726:230482] 
Unhandled Exception:
System.Exception: No class inheriting from a valid Application Delegate found in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDEADCEA-707F-4FEF-AE7E-B29A25BE7348/Documents/xamarin.iOS.content/xamarin.iOS.exe
  at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.Run (System.String[] args, System.Action`1[T] loadFrameworkAction, System.Action killApplicationAction) <0x104a28c68 + 0x001b6> in <98b03165b3364c75930281f33d5e323b>:0 
  at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/winios/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS/Main.cs:12 

2022-10-25 11:11:52.347 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3726:230482] Unhandled managed exception: No class inheriting from a valid Application Delegate found in /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DDEADCEA-707F-4FEF-AE7E-B29A25BE7348/Documents/xamarin.iOS.content/xamarin.iOS.exe (System.Exception)
  at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application.Run (System.String[] args, System.Action`1[T] loadFrameworkAction, System.Action killApplicationAction) <0x104a28c68 + 0x001b6> in <98b03165b3364c75930281f33d5e323b>:0 
  at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/winios/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS/Main.cs:12 


=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================

Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x102590290 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info

    0x102586ce0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x10258f7d8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : sigabrt_signal_handler
    0x1f03e1c10 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1f03ef3bc - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : pthread_kill
    0x18b506524 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort

    0x102719c60 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type

    0x1025e8eb4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook

    0x102586924 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_exception_internal

    0x1025852f8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_exception

    0x102736594 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_throw

    0x102735de8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

    0x10272bc38 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke

    0x102596f18 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke

    0x102643a9c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked

    0x102648d10 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked

    0x10257b850 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec

    0x102729bbc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main

    0x1025405a8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4EF71A9D-44BC-4BB0-A90C-C3F9396630CF/xamarin.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x102e79da4 - Unknown

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================

Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1b7265b38):0x1b7265b28  ff 0f 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6 10 29 80 d2 01 
10 00 d4  .._..._..)..
....
0x1b7265b38  03 01 00 54 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ...T.#...{......
0x1b7265b48  a6 ed ff 97 bf 03 00 91 fd 
7b c1 a8 ff 0f 5f d6  .........{...._.
0x1b7265b58  c0 03 5f d6 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91 
 .._..#...{......

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
=================================================================

Thread started: <Thread Pool> #9
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #10
The app has been terminated.
```

The AppDelegate.cs of the project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;

namespace VinInfoApp.iOS
{
    // The UIApplicationDelegate for the application. This class is responsible for launching the 
    // User Interface of the application, as well as listening (and optionally responding) to 
    // application events from iOS.
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

What's the issue here? how can I get it running?

Comment: You used the autogenerated example Xamarin Application in VisualStudio, it means that you created an empty Xamarin project, right? How did you download your app to your iPhone? By looking at the logs, you used HotRestart. Did you configure the developer information for your project? And could you describe more about how you use hot restart?

Comment: I connected the Iphone, installed the itunes and followed the instructions. It compiled and downloaded to the Iphone. After the starting notice, I started the app and this failure appeared 1 second after start.

Comment: According to the log you provided, there is an error in your AppDelegate, can you provide the code of your AppDelegate? You can also check if you have Storyboards and XIB files in your project, if you use hot restart, your app may crash when the app tries to load these files at runtime. For more details, please refer to this document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/deployment/hot-restart#prevent-code-from-executing

Comment: The AppDelegate code is provided now in the question section.

Comment: Could you tell me which version of iOS did you tested with?

Comment: On the iPad (9.generation) there is Software Version 15.7 and on the iPhone 11 iOs Vers 16.0.3 (20A392). For both devices, I get the same results

Comment: You can try to test HotRestart with other project instead of VS auto-generated instance, for iOS16 you try to turn on developer mode in iPhone.

Comment: I've have tested it first with another solution. Same result. I used here the autogenerated solution in order to make the failure easier to reproduce. It is very strange for me, that the in visual studio newly generated example doesn't work, and no other seems to have the same issue like me?

Comment: Did you test other projects with HotRestart and the crash message is the same as this one?

Comment: I've now updated to VS 17.4.0 and tried again. I made an empty project, and it now worked. For me this issue is threfore closed. Dongzhi thanks for your support.